# Trying to read yy from 2022/04/17 at position 0 - in flutter

Tags: flutter

This is how I used the time and date output format,
To get time on this item "getCartListHistory [itemCounter] .time"

```
Widget getDataTime(){
  DateTime parseData = DateFormat('yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').parse(getCartListHistory[itemCounter].time!);
  var inputDate = DateTime.parse(parseData.toString());
  var outPutFormat = DateFormat.yMd().add_jm();
  var outputDate = outPutFormat.format(inputDate);
  return BigText(text: outputDate);
}
```

Comment: Other formats such as
yyyy / MM / dd
I have also tried

Comment: what is the problem

Comment: error - Trying to read yy from 2022/04/17 at position 0

Comment: `yy/MM/dd` is wrong; that expects a two-digit year. `var dateTime = DateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd').parse('2022/04/17');` works for me.  If it doesn't work for you, post a reproducible example with the exact input string.  Please verify that you don't have extraneous whitespace at the beginning of your input string.  Also, `DateTime.parse(parseData.toString())` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

try pass also the time when parsing it will read same pattern on DateFormat

```
 DateTime parseData = DateFormat('y/MM/dd HH:mm:ss').parse("2022/04/17 09:24:00");
  var inputDate = DateTime.parse(parseData.toString());
  var outPutFormat = DateFormat.yMd().add_jm();
var outputDate = outPutFormat.format(inputDate);
    log(outputDate.toString());
```

result :

```
4/17/2022 9:24 AM
```